# Add UITabBarController or similar User Interface View on the UIViewController other than rootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to create an app that navigates from the rootViewController using `UINavigationBar` to the nextViewController which is `UITabBarController` or similar `UIView` with `UITabBar` with couple of `UITabBarItems`. So please suggest. Suggestions for both programmatic and using Interface Builder would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to image what you're trying to produce so let me give two scenarios. A) The first view the user sees has a navigation bar but no tab bar. When they do some action they are taken to the next view which does have a tab bar. B) The first view the user sees has a navigation bar AND a tab bar. Are either correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the Apple' docs you'll see that it's clear that Apple think that UITabBarController's should only be used as the root view controller.

I believe the exception to this is perhaps where you have say an interim view controller for login before you enter the enter the app proper.

If you want a tabBarController type behaviour inside a navigationController based app then you should probably be using UIViewControllers with UIToolBars inside UINavigationController and not a UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/) post can help you. I'm trying to do a custom tab bar (like foursquare) with Storyboard...